# asp.net mvc [Authorize()] attribute for mixed group and user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I am using ASP.NET MVC 1.1 with Windows authentication.  I trying to only authorize members of a group and myself.  I am not a member of the group and would not need to be a member of this group. I am getting windows login/password prompt every time I access the URL of the web app. The HomeController has

```
[HandleError]
[Authorize(Roles=@"MyDomain\\company.security.group.name")]  
[Authorize(Users=@"MyDoamin\\MyName")]
[OutputCache(Duration=86400,VaryByParam="PageIndex")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

How do I enable such authorization?  The web app is running under a site on IIS6. The site has directory security to accept anonymous.  The web app/virtual directory has anonymous disabled and Windows Integrated security enabled.  The web.config has

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can subtype `AuthorizeAttribute` to look at Users *and* Roles. off the top of my head (untested):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    // This method must be thread-safe since it is called by the thread-safe OnCacheAuthorization() method.
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
        base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Users) && (_usersSplit.Length == 0)) ||
           (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Roles) && (_rolesSplit.Length == 0)))
        {
            // wish base._usersSplit were protected instead of private...
            InitializeSplits();                
        }

        IPrincipal user = httpContext.User;
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            return false;
        }

        var userRequired = _usersSplit.Length > 0;
        var userValid = userRequired
            && _usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        var roleRequired = _rolesSplit.Length > 0;
        var roleValid = (roleRequired) 
            && _rolesSplit.Any(user.IsInRole);

        var userOrRoleRequired = userRequired || roleRequired;

        return (!userOrRoleRequired) || userValid || roleValid;
    }

    private string[] _rolesSplit = new string[0];
    private string[] _usersSplit = new string[0];

    private void InitializeSplits()
    {
        lock(this)
        {
            if ((_rolesSplit.Length == 0) || (_usersSplit.Length == 0))
            {
                _rolesSplit = Roles.Split(',');
                _usersSplit = Users.Split(',');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is something missing in the posted the custom attribute code.  I managed to debug and compiled it.  It didn't work.  Here is the attribute declaration. [MyAuthorize(Roles=@"MyDomain\\company.security.group.name",Users=@"MyDoamin\\MyName"))]

Comment: I know this is an old post, but what you seem to have missed is that `@` eliminates the need to escape your backslashes. When you do both, you create a string literal that contains two backslashes, instead of the single slash that you need.

Comment: SplitString is not accessible in this context.

Answer (score 13):

As you are prefixing your domain/user and domain/group strings with the '@' character you do not need to double escape the backslash. You could try replacing these lines with either:

```
[Authorize(Roles="MyDomain\\company.security.group.name")]  
[Authorize(Users="MyDoamin\\MyName")]
```

or

```
[Authorize(Roles=@"MyDomain\company.security.group.name")]  
[Authorize(Users=@"MyDoamin\MyName")]
```

A bit of further reading has also revealed that the Authorize filter will perform a 'users' and 'roles' check. If the user doesn't meet both requirements then they will be refused access.
To get the behaviour you want you will need to write a custom authorisation filter as suggested in a previous answer.