# MVC3 Authorize Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authorize

How to add Roles and Users to the same action on a controller.

I tried:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin" , Users = "userName")]
public ActionResult Action()
{
....
....
}

[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
[Authorize(Users = "userName")]
public ActionResult Action()
{
....
....
}
```

Do i have to create a custom Authorize Attribute?

Thanks

Comment: What error do you get for your first attempt? It should be fine..

Comment: no error.. the window authentication pop up and i enter valid username and password and the window authentication kept pop up everytime i enter username and password which mean the thinks the username and password is invalid. But when i try with just Roles works fine or with just Users

Comment: I see, check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/4672058/944681

Comment: You need a custom attribute.  The default functionality is that when you use users and roles it requires you to be one of the listed users and also in one of the listed roles.  This is well-explained in Michael Klouda's link.  Here's a related link as well:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136979/asp-net-mvc-authorize-attribute-for-mixed-group-and-user

Comment: Found this question when I was trying to solve a similar problem. Solved it by creating a custom authorize attribute using the example from the link and then adding a bit of extra functionality to the example: http://www.syntaxwarriors.com/2011/mvc3-custom-authorizeattribute/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way:

```
[Authorize(Users="userName", Roles="admin")]
```

Comment: According to Michal Klouda link if I read correct... 
[Authorize(Users="userName", Roles="admin")] mean username has to be in the Users and Roles to be authenticate. But my list of Users is different then Roles. I try by adding a username in Users that is also in Roles and it work fine.

Comment: so this doesn't not work for what i want to do because userName is not on the group admin.